# How to solve for $n$?

Tags: calculus, integration

e.g.

$$\int_1^n \frac{1}{x} dx = \pi$$

I want to know the method used to solve it for any constant $c$ of any integral.

Comment: $\ln n =\pi$, i.e. $n = e^{\pi}$.

Comment: @njguliyev So in general, you set the antiderivative equal to the $c$ that is sought and solve for n?

Comment: Almost. Actually we have $\ln n - \ln 1 = \pi$, so for other functions do not forget about the point $1$.

Comment: @zerosofthezeta : there is only one real solution, $e^\pi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\int_1^n \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln (n) = \pi$ therefore $e^{\ln n} = e^{\pi} = n.$